# what is the purpose of reassigning a variable inside a for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner, so I was solving an exercise which is a function to return the first unrepeated letter in a string, my answer did not work at all, so when I looked at the solution I found that it was similar to mine except that the answer sheet had reassigned a global variable inside a for loop, and the reassignment did not even change the value of the variable.
would you please explain why do you need to reassign for the function to work properly.

here is my code:

```
function find(str) {  

  var array = str.split('');  
  var result = '';  
  var counter = 0; // counter declared here 

  for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {  
    //counter missing here

    for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {  

      if (array[x] === array[y]) { counter = counter + 1;} 
    }  



    if (counter < 2) {  
      result = array[x];  
      break;  
    }  
  }  



  return result;  
}
```

and this is the code from the answer sheet that worked properly:

```
function find(str) {  

  var array = str.split('');  
  var result = '';  
  var counter = 0;  //counter declared here

  for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {  
    counter = 0; //counter is reassigned here 

    for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {  

      if (array[x] === array[y]) { counter = counter + 1;} 
    }  



    if (counter < 2) {  
      result = array[x];  
      break;  
    }  
  }  



  return result;  
}
```

Comment: `counter` is actually not a global variable, because it's declared inside of a function -- that makes it a local variable (local to that function).

Comment: sorry I meant global to the loop not to the whole function, in other words counter not declared as a variable inside the loop

Comment: Think about the value of `counter`. What difference does it make to have the line `counter = 0` inside the loop? Run both functions in your mind (or on a sheet of paper), line by line and iteration by iteration. Look at the differences and how they affect the result.

Answer (score 1):

> the reassignment did not even change the value of the variable.

Yes it does.

Notice that the `counter` variable is supposed to be local to the outer loop, instead of being global to both loops (like in your code). It might better be written

```
function find(str) {
  var array = str.split('');
  var result = '';
//var counter; (hoisted)
  for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {  
    var counter = 0;
//  ^^^
    for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
      if (array[x] === array[y]) counter = counter + 1;
    }
    if (counter < 2) {
      result = array[x];
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;  
}
```

But as `var`s are always scoped to the function, it doesn't matter where the `var` declaration is placed. It does matter though that the the variable is (re)initialised with `0` at the begin of every turn of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the interior loop, the value of counter is assigned to 0 before starting the process of the sub-for (second one). Note that the break situation depends on your counter value.

if array.length = 5 with elements:{1,2,1,3,4} then

```
counter   x    y
0         0    0  (initial) 

0         0    0  (if array[0] == array[0]) counter++
1         0    1  (if array[0] == array[1]) nothinghappens
1         0    2  (if array[0] == array[2]) counter++
2         0    3  (if array[0] == array[3]) nothinghappens
2         0    4  (if array[0] == array[4]) nothinghappens
```

counter < 2 => NO  so increase X, set counter 0 and loop again!

```
counter   x    y
0         1    0  (initial-2) 

0         1    0  (initial-2) if (array[1] = array[0]) nothinghappens
0         1    1  (initial-2) if (array[1] = array[1]) counter++
1         1    2  (initial-2) if (array[1] = array[2]) nothinghappens
0         1    3  (initial-2) if (array[1] = array[3]) nothinghappens
0         1    4  (initial-2) if (array[1] = array[4]) nothinghappens
```

here counter < 2, so result = array[1] = 2;

This is how your serverside-code works. If you do not set counter to 0 before starting second for loop, we would not get the correct result because counter value would be 3 in this case and looping would go on..